# Finding list elements that have exactly two nested elements with the same values in python

Tags: python, list, loops

Ive got a list (A) with 2 nested elements.

```
A=[[[['a1', 'a1'], ['b1', 'b1'], ['c1', 'c2']],[['a1', 'a1'], ['b1', 'b1'], ['c1','c1']]], [[m], [1-m]]]
```

The elements in A[1] (`[[m], [1-m]]`) are the 'probabilities' associated with the elements in A[0] , for example [m] is the probability for A[0][0] [['a1', 'a1'], ['b1', 'b1'], ['c1', 'c2']].

I need to find a way to add the elements from A[0] that have only 2 nested elements with the same values inside, as well as the probability associated with that element (found in A[1]) to a new list. For example, only the first element in A[0] (ie. `[['a1', 'a1'], ['b1', 'b1'], ['c1', 'c2']]`] has two internal nest elements that have the same thing inside them ([a1, a1] and [b1,b1]). The second A[0] element has 3 internal element with the same values inside so this wouldn't count.

So the new list would be like.

```
B=[[['a1', 'a1'], ['b1', 'b1'], ['c1', 'c2']], [[m]]]
```

Ive attempted to work it out through a series of for loops like such,

```
for i in A[0]:
    for j in i:
        for k in i:
            if j[0]==j[1]:
                if k[0]==k[1]:
                    B=[]
                    B.append(i)
```

however, this only gives out A[0][1], which is not the one I want, and Im also not sure how to approach getting  the probabilities into B. Any input on how to fix the code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's write a list comprehension, something like below.

1. It iterates over the `sublist` and probability `p` pair zipped together (`zip(A[0], A[1]`), and returns only those sublists, which have exactly 2 pairs same.
2. For the second part (if condition), we iterate over each of the pairs `i` in `sublist` and check if after taking a `set()`, their length is equal to 1. If yes then they have repeated elements.
3. Next, we sum up the booleans for that sublist `True=1`, `False=0`. If the sum is 2 (there are exactly 2 `True`s), then the sublist contains exactly `2 pairs with repeated elements` and is returned by the list comprehension, along with its corresponding probability.

```
m = 0.2

A=[[[['a1', 'a1'], ['b1', 'b1'], ['c1', 'c2']],[['a1', 'a1'], ['b1', 'b1'], ['c1','c1']]], [[m], [1-m]]]

[[sublist,p] for sublist,p in zip(A[0], A[1]) if sum([len(set(i))==1 for i in sublist])==2]
```

```
[[[['a1', 'a1'], ['b1', 'b1'], ['c1', 'c2']], [0.2]]]
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you for the explanation as well!

Comment: Welcome, Glad to help.